# How chrome is mapping XHR calls to TCP sockets

Tags: google-chrome, sockets, tcp

I have a query, I tried to get an answer on google a lot, not getting any clear cut answer (for Chrome).

How does the individual XHR call map to the underlying TCP socket in Http 1.1 context?

Pardon me to explain my situation.

In my workflow, I keep on polling my server with a set of REST APIs (more than 6) on a polling frequency of say 5 min.  I have workflows as well besides the continuous polling - usual CRUD workflows which consist of 1 or more REST API calls. So at a given time, I have the pooling APIs plus one/more workflow APIs.

I often see some of the workflow REST APIs are 'stalled' in browser for not getting the TCP socket, I guess.

So I started controlling the concurrency of the polling APIs. How many REST APIs I can allow to execute concurrently in the polling? So I started with reducing the number from 6, 5, 4 .... 1 with the assumption that when I call with a number, say 2 .. only two TCP sockets will be occupied by the polling REST APIs. The rest 4 TCP sockets will be available for the workflow APIs.

So basically by monotonically decreasing the pooling API numbers (from 6 downto 1), my expectation is more and more TCP sockets will be available for workflow APIs - hence workflow will execute faster (as more TCP channels are of disposal for workflow APIs).

However the result is not reflecting the same. It's somewhat non deterministic.

What assumption am I making wrong? Most likely my 1 API to 1 TCP socket mapping seems a flawed conception.

How do I learn more about the XHR call to TCP socker mapping? I tried with chrome://net-internals (it's now truncated), tried with chrome://net-export. However I am unable to find out the mapping heuristic of XHR calls to the socket scheduled via Chrome. So my simplified assumptions are, most likely, not working as expected.

If you can please throw some lights what mistake I am having in my understanding, it would really be helpful.

Thanks,
Pradip

Comment: I’m not sure why the TCP sockets/connections are interesting. It’s more of how to make it work. Do you mean you’re long polling something? Or just every five minutes sending a request and getting an answer immediately?

Comment: Yeah, its a long pooling. Unfortunately, some of the polling API calls runs quite a few minute to return back.

Comment: I don't have an answer for your question, but have you considered using WebSockets instead of XHR? With WS the browser will understand that the connection is going to be long lasting.

Comment: We are evaluating http2 as well as WSS. @KevinReid - which one would be 'best suited' you think?